# Changing height of a div on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm doing a web application using reactjs. And I have a need of changing the height of a div when I'm scrolling down and restore to the original height when I'm scrolling up. I'm not sure if there's a CSS only solution to what I need. What's the way of achieving what i have described above.

```
class InternalGroupsPage extends Component {
     constructor() {
     super();
}

render() {

return (
         <div className="body_clr">

            <div className="group_page_header">
                    This is the div i want to change the height when scrolling
            </div>

            <div>
                    Other stuff
            </div>
         </div>

        );
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.group_page_header {

    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    background-color: #0b97c4;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;

}

.body_clr {

    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #eceff1;

}
```

Comment: Where's your react component codes?

Comment: I have given only the html and css because i didn't think other codes were necessary.Anyway i have updated now

Comment: If you can provide me a fiddle with the above code working, I can do it for you. 
Basically you need to toggle a state variable + className when the `scrollTop` passes a certain point for the rerender to happen.
 Makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically like I mentioned in the comment.

Basically you need to toggle a state variable + className when the scrollTop passes a certain point for the rerender to happen.

Here's the handle scroll function:

```
handleScroll(event) {
      var scrollTop = event.srcElement.body.scrollTop;
      var isScrollUp = this.getScrollDirection();

      if(isScrollUp) {
        this.setState({
          hideHeader: true,
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          hideHeader: false,
        });
      }
  };
```

To detect the scroll direction:

```
getScrollDirection() {
    var currentScrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    var isScrollUp = currentScrollTop < this.previousScrollTop;
    this.previousScrollTop = currentScrollTop;
    return isScrollUp;
  }
```

And the render function to toggle the classes

```
 render() {
    var headerClassName = this.state.hideHeader ? `group_page_header hideHeader` : `group_page_header showHeader`;
    console.log('classNAme ->', headerClassName)
    return (
      <div className="body_clr">
        <div className={headerClassName}>
        This is the div i want to change the height when scrolling
        </div>
        <div className="other-stuff">
          Other stuff
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nevinm/9c9vtxxu/8/)**

You can update your small css changes and try it out. Basically this should be the direction you should be following to attain this requirement.

Comment: i did like you have done here. But the state won't change on scroll. the console.log prints only group_page_header showHeader when scrolling.

Comment: @CraZyDroiD I would need your code for me to explain more. Basically am assuming the answer I have provided is the one you want?

Comment: i want something like this

http://callmenick.com/_development/resize-header-on-scroll/

Comment: @CraZyDroiD 
Told you right, you can update the css according to your needs.
Check the updated fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/nevinm/9c9vtxxu/6/

Comment: i used your code and to some extent it works. but what is the use of .hideHeader ? even if i delete that class it works. And when i use your code, instead of reducing the header height, mine disappears when scrolling.

Comment: @CraZyDroiD It's used to manipulate the height of the div. Check the css. You will understand.
https://jsfiddle.net/nevinm/9c9vtxxu/8/

Comment: @CraZyDroiD If you found the answer useful, upvote and accept it. Will help the rest of the people looking for the same requriement.